# FlipClock.js display an image when the countdown is over

Tags: jquery, flipclock

I'm using [FlipClock 1.1a](http://flipclockjs.com/) and I want to set an image when the countdown is over and hide the counter. Currently, the counter goes in - time (-1 hour, -12 minutes) when the time is up. How can I do this? The site has very few callback and its not helping.

Comment: They have very clear documentation. What did you try so far?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They have provided different example in their code base which do include counter stop event. So, you need to use `stop` callback of **FlipClock** performing the required operation,

```
 var clock;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(10, {
            clockFace: 'MinuteCounter',
            countdown: true,
            callbacks: {
                stop: function() {
                    // Do whatever you want to do here,
                    // that may include hiding the clock 
                    // or displaying the image you mentioned
                    $('.message').html('The clock has stopped!');
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

P.S

If you have downloaded their whole source file you can check out the demo itself *`/FlipClock-master/examples/countdown-stop-callback.html`*

Comment: hello,i have tried the callback but blown in the console call maximum call stack size exceeded! i was trying to use in a Exam javascript app! however i found alternative ways to fix it but may i know the reason why it gone blown!

Comment: oh thank you! i figured out - the problem was i recursively called the stop function and callback was executing as infinite loop!

Comment: bad library with horrible documents! events don't work! callbacks too. thanks for help. you save me some hours.